# Apache HTTPD Virtual Host,what is %1+ in a document root?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

So I have a Virtual Host set up and I snagged this as my Document Root

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/sites/%1+/www"
```

Everything works great but this one thing has been killing me. Does anyone have any idea what %1+ means? Could someone breakdown exactly what it is and how it works. I understand it is pointing the server to where to look but what is `%1+` doing?

Comment: It might be better to ask this on Ask Different, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Graham Not everything that mentions "Mac" is material for AD, this is purely an Apache question.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Neither the question nor the subject mentioned Apache (I didn't see the tag) so I just assumed it was a Mac specific thing. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: no problem, I did create an AD account though because of you LOL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

> All the directives in this module interpolate a string into a
>   pathname. The interpolated string [...] may be either the server name
>   [...] or the IP address of the virtual host on the server in
>   dotted-quad format. The interpolation is controlled by specifiers
>   inspired by printf which have a number of formats:
>
> ```
> [...]
> %N.M  insert (part of) the name
> ```
>
> N and M are used to specify substrings of the name. N selects from the
>   dot-separated components of the name, and M selects characters within
>   whatever N has selected. M is optional and defaults to zero if it
>   isn't present; the dot must be present if and only if M is present.
>   The interpretation is as follows:
>
> ```
> 0   the whole name
> 1   the first part
> [...]
> 2+  the second and all subsequent parts
> [...]
> ```
>
> For a very large number of virtual hosts it is a good idea to arrange
>   the files to reduce the size of the vhosts directory. To do this you
>   might use the following in your configuration file:
>
> ```
> UseCanonicalName Off
> VirtualDocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/vhosts/%3+/%2.1/%2.2/%2.3/%2
> ```
>
> A request for http://www.domain.example.com/directory/file.html will
>   be satisfied by the file
>   /usr/local/apache/vhosts/example.com/d/o/m/domain/directory/file.html.

So, in

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/sites/%1+/www"
```

the request

```
www.example.com
```

would resolve to

```
/sites/www.example.com/www
```